# Is there a way to save the file listing from a Windows file search to a text file?

Tags: windows-xp

Is there a way to save the file listing from a  Windows search to a text file?

I have had to search from My Computer over 6 drives for a file spec. I can't believe that there is no way to save the results to a file, or is there?

Comment: What about using "Everything"? Or for searching files, use "WinGrep". I know, this is not the 'solution' 1:1, but may help you in an other way.

Comment: I have tried this and it fits my need. It's not integrated with Windows Explorer, but does all I'm looking for

Comment: Good to hear that! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Select all results (`Ctrl+A`).
2. Right-click on the results, while keeping the shift key pressed.
3. Pick "Copy as path" from the context menu (only appears when shift is pressed).
4. Paste clipboard into Notepad.
5. Save.

**NOTE**: "Copy as path" only exists as of Windows Vista. On Windows XP, you can try Gabriele Ponti's [Send To Toys](http://www.gabrieleponti.com/software/).

Comment: which version if Windows is it? The "Copy as path" is not available  in Windows XP. I am just praying that it can be that easy if possible at all

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a third-party solution for Windows XP.

Comment: You might better place the note at top of the answer, I feel.

Comment: I have read the info on  Send To Toys, and it appears to check only the file names. I will try it out on a separate system